# Revalidate an element when changed programmatically with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using JQuery Validate plugin, and validating inputs this way. An input has been marked as invalid, after submitting form once.

There is a field, "from", whose value is linked to another field, "to". How do I get the field "to" to revalidate once "from" has been changed?

HTML:

```
<div id="fromPanel" class="inputPanel">
<label>From</label>
<div class="invalid valid" generated="true" for="from"></div>
<select id="from" class="campusChooser valid" required="required" name="from">
<option value="" disabled="disabled"> -- Choose a Campus -- </option>
<option selected="selected" value="UTSG">St. George</option>
<option value="UTM">Mississauga</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="toPanel" class="inputPanel">
<label>To</label>
<div class="invalid" generated="true" for="to"></div>
<select id="to" class="campusChooser" required="required" name="to">
<option value="" disabled="disabled"> -- Choose a Campus -- </option>
<option value="UTSG">St. George</option>
<option selected="selected" value="UTM">Mississauga</option>
</select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
$("#to").change(function() {
var otherField = field == "to" ? "from" : "to", otherValue;
if (value == "UTSG") {
        otherValue = "UTM";
    } else if (value == "UTM") {
        otherValue = "UTSG";
    } else {
        otherValue = "";
    }

    $("#" + otherField).find("option[value='{0}']".format(otherValue)).prop("selected", true);
}); 
});
```

Comment: Trigger the change event, or blur, whatever the validation is looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can programatically trigger a validation test using [the `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/).  You can attach `.valid()` to a single input element or to the whole form.

```
$('#myform').valid();
```

or

```
$('input[name="fieldName"]').valid();
```

Calling `.valid()` will immediately trigger a validation test on the selected element(s) as well as returning a boolean value.

(Note:  `validate()` needs to be called on the form before checking it using this method.)

See: http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/

Answer (score 0):

To force validation on a specific textbox you can simply do $('your selector').valid();